# How can I import mdx file using NextJS router

Tags: next.js, mdx, next.js13, mdxjs

I want to get MDX file data according to the routers (if the file MDX is present with that name) for example

```
domain.com/test
domain.com/focus
domain.com/space
```

So, the code will check if the files are present inside the mdx-pages folder such as

```
test.mdx
focus.mdx
space.mdx
```

But, I am currently facing the issue that my code gives me the following error

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Below is my code link

https://pastebin.com/epQ3Ldyn

Also, I am a bit confused about where to put the routing and fetching code

Note:- I am using NEXT JS 14, MDX, and Gray Matter.

**Updated :**

```
const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')()
 
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // Configure `pageExtensions` to include MDX files
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'mdx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  // Optionally, add any other Next.js config below
}
 
module.exports = withMDX(nextConfig)
```

My MDX FILE -> https://pastebin.com/89A6QRwD

Comment: you can instead configure nextjs to render mdx pages instead of manually checking for the mdx template to exist

Comment: @sid Yes, I already have mdx mentioned inside next.config.js

Comment: so navigating to the route should render the mdx, would be helpful if you add any errors that you see

Comment: @sid Also I have Executed mdx by importing it as component and it's working the only thing i want to make it dynamic according to the routers

Comment: @sid Also I want to implement meta tags let me share you my mdx file

Comment: @sid updated my code and added MDX file link

Comment: "make it dynamic according to the routers" - what exactly?

Comment: @sid I want  that inside my dynamic routes it reads the slug and check if the mdx files exist with the same name and then it implements the data accordingly for each mdx file Let me know if it clear's what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: from what you have in example, if you create 3 mdx files for test, focus and space with .mdx extension and navigate to the page, it would work. does it not? any errors?

Comment: @sid  I have sort my query with next-mdx-remote. Thank's for your reply.